# Help decoding MSDN Dynamic Data Article

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, msdn

I'm trying to run through this msdn article:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd723645.aspx
One of the steps is:

> In the class file for the page, change the base class from UserControl to EntityTemplateUserControl.

Nowhere is it made clear what page is being referenced. Can someone help me? I don't see any relevant class in the pages I have, so I assumed maybe they were talking about the ascx and didn't *really* mean page, but I'm not seeing an option there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. They do mean the control and not the page. So, we create an ascx control (e.g. mycontrol.ascx) and then we replace this line:

```
Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl
```

With this one:

```
Inherits EntityTemplateUserControl
```